# How to do this for loop in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I was wondering if you can help me doing this for loop in Excel?

I would be able to do it with Java or C, but with Excel is very hard!! I saw some beginer tutorials, but it is so complicated!!

`S(i) and T(i) are to explain that I need to go from S3 to S32, and T3 to T32`

```
{
INT C4  = Intro!B5
INT var = 0

FOR i = 3 to 32
    IF  S(i) = INTRO!A12    THEN
        IF  T(i) = 0    THEN
            var = INTRO!B2
        ELSE    var = INTRO!B2 - T(i)
        ENDIF
    ELSE    var = 0
    ENDIF

    C4 = C4 - var
    i++
ENDFOR
}
```

This is what I tried but it doesn't work!

```
Sub title()

Dim i As Integer
Dim var As Integer
var.Value = 0

For i = 3 To 32
    If Cells(4,3).Value = "C" Then
        If Cells(i, 19) = 0 Then
            var = INTRO.Cells(2,2)
        Else: var = INTRO.Cells(2,2) - Cells(i,20)
        End If
    Else: var = 0
    Enf If
Cells(4,3) = Cells(4,3) - var
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What are S and T meant to be? You would be better off explaining what you are hoping to achieve to be honest, I have convereted it but it makes no sense, you have an if to determine what T(i) is and if it isn't zero then minus it from a number, why even test it? just minus it every time as it won't minus anything when it is zero. Then there are a couple of arrays with no indication what they are. Also when you put INTRO!B2 does that mean range B2 on the sheet INTRO?

Comment: the cells! S3, S4, to S32!

Comment: intro b2 and b5 are just number. I don't think it is important! Is the cell B2 in the sheet INTRO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I based this off your attempted conversion, there are a few mistakes but I think I cleaned them all up:

```
Sub title()
Dim i As Long, var As Long
var = 0
For i = 3 To 32
    If Cells(4, 3).Value = "C" Then
        If Cells(i, 19) = 0 Then
            var = Sheets("INTRO").Cells(2, 2).Value
        Else
            var = Sheets("INTRO").Cells(2, 2).Value - Cells(i, 20).Value
        End If
    Else
        var = 0
    End If
    Cells(4, 3) = Cells(4, 3) - var
Next
End Sub
```

Note in VBA use Long instead of Integer and assign directly, var=0 not var.value = 0 as it's a variable not an object.

Also there was a typo `enf if` instead of `end if`

Comment: THANKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS

Comment: Hey Dan! I have 2 questions with your code. The first is, are Macros mandatory in this case or we can avoid using them? And, I need to repeat all this Macro 12 times. So, with Sheets("Januray").Cells(4, 3) to December. How would you do it? In java I would use an array with [12] and a for loop that follows all the Strings in that array, but I don't know if we can do this in Excel!

Comment: To be honest, without understanding your sheet I would hazard a guess that a nested if formula would actually do the job without Excel. As for multiple sheets, again using a formula would negate that need but if you wanted to do it in code I would use the same method, Array with 12 elements then cycle through. If you want to go down this path let me know and I will help you.

Comment: Sorry that should read without Macros, not without Excel lol

Comment: Ok yeah thanks for the info! And yes please, can you teach me how to do :D It would be awesome!

Comment: Hey! Can you please see it and help me with some errors :O 
https://codeshare.io/5N8W91

Comment: I have jumped over to your other question as this one was closed. Keep further questions in that one so if anyone searches for the same issue in the future they will find an answer (Closed questions don't appear in search)